# razor html to string using Quartz

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email, razor, quartz.net

I have been trying to obtain a html and translate the razor code in a string to send and email to multiple users. The emails are scheduled by `Quartz` and send to the users.

The mail is generating a link via `@Url.Action`. I notice that I don't have a `Controller` nor `HttpContext` at this point on my application. I have been trying a way to translate the `razor` code (`RazorEngine` and `MvcMailer`) to a string and sending in the email, but with no use because I cannot translate the `@Url.Action` and can't find a working package `MvcMailer` for Visual Studio 2017

Is there a way to possible do this?

Here is the template of the Email:

```
Hi @ViewBag.RecipientName,

Client that buy this item is @Model.ClientName 
<p> <a href='@Url.Action("Index", "Item", new { ItemId = Model.ItemId}, Request.Url.Scheme)'>Click here to check the Item</a> </p>

@ViewBag.RecipientEmailAddress
```

Here is the email generator

```
public MailMessage GetMessage(EmailModel notification)
{

    string BodyTemplate = ReplaceEmailBody(notification);

    return new MailMessage
    {
        To = { "testuser@testdomain.com" },
        Subject = DateTime.Now.ToString(),
        IsBodyHtml = true,
        Body = BodyTemplate
    };
}
```

Here is my rubbish attempt to replace the razor:

```
    private string ReplaceEmailBody(EmailModel notification)
    {
        string notificationBody = "";

        notificationBody = Templates.Resources.MailTemplate;

        notificationBody = notificationBody.Replace("@ViewBag.RecipientName", notification.RecipientName);
        notificationBody = notificationBody.Replace("@ViewBag.RecipientEmailAddress", notification.RecipientEmailAddress);
        notificationBody = notificationBody.Replace("@Model.CLIENT_NAME", notification.ClientName);

        //Need to replace the Url.Action
    }
```

All this code is running in a execute job of `Quartz`

I'm using Visual Studio 2017

Comment: You can provide url (mvc controller action) to your quartz service which will be called to generate razor email (and eventually send it).

Comment: @StanislavNedeljkovic And how can I do that?

Comment: If url is static put it in config file, if it is dynamic send it as job param.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Stanislav Nedeljkovic suggested, I put the Url on a config file and manage to create and `HttpContext` with it. Then I could translate the rest with `RazorEngine`.

```
        var request = new HttpRequest("/", ConfigFile.Url, "");
        var response = new HttpResponse(new StringWriter());
        httpContext = new HttpContext(request, response);


        var httpContextBase = new HttpContextWrapper(httpContext);
        var routeData = new RouteData();
        var requestContext = new RequestContext(httpContextBase, routeData);

        var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(requestContext);
        var url = urlHelper.Action("Index", "Item", new { ItemId = model.itemId});
```